# MATLAB: (Good Ol') Error in MuPAD command

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, symbolic-computation

I know many a question like this has been asked before, but the cases that I've seen are more complicated (i.e. I don't understand them) and the answers seem to pertain only to the specific cases.

My case is very simple (and thus broadly applicable), taken from MATLAB's very own [help page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/syms.html):

```
syms x
f(x) = [x x^2; x^3 x^4];
f(2)
```

The output is supposed to be as follows:

```
ans =
[ 2,  4]
[ 8, 16]
```

But instead I get this error message. How come? And how do I fix it? Thanks.

```
If the input expression contains a symbolic variable, use the VPA
function instead.

Error in ==> sym.sym>sym.double at 936
            Xstr = mupadmex('symobj::double', S.s, 0);

Error in ==> sym.sym>privformatscalar at 2678
    x = double(x);

Error in ==> sym.sym>privformat at 2663
    s = privformatscalar(x);

Error in ==> sym.sym>sym.subsasgn at 1433
                [inds{k},refs{k}] = privformat(inds{k});
```

Comment: Please state the exact error message that you get. If it is something about `Undifined function syms` you probably don't have the symbolic toolbox. Also, if you want to use examples, always find them via the `help syms` or `doc syms` rather than the website, that way you are always sure the examples are made for your version of Matlab.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Okay, full error message added. I do have the symbolic toolbox, but your suggestion about version differences is good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chances are you have an older version of MATLAB (this code doesn't work for me on 2011b either).  This should be equivalent:

```
syms x
f = [x x^2; x^3 x^4];
subs(f,2);
```

Comment: That works on my 2011a! Many thanks. Is it just a matter of MATLAB's deciding to change syntax in a newer version? I must admit to having been practically oblivious to MATLAB's versions just because they all look the same. Will pay more attention from now on.